# #VALUE error when dealing with long string in UDF in VBA(excel)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-udf

I've encountered #VALUE error when using an UDF returning an array with long strings (>256 symbols).

Sample Code:

```
Function longString() As Variant
        Dim res(1 To 1, 1 To 2)
        res(1, 1) = "hellohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\nhellohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\nhellohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\nhellohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhellohh\n"
        res(1, 2) = "world"
        longString = res
End Function
```

When calling longString()  as an array formula in a cell, the cell got #Value error, but through debugging, longString() returns without error.

how can i  resolve this issue?

Comment: Your code doesn't throw any error on my machine (Excel 2010). What version are you on?

Comment: @silentsurfer Did you enter the UDF as a formula in a worksheet cell?  It returns a `#VALUE!` error in that cell in Excel 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have run into one of the obscure limitations in the interactions between VBA and Excel.

One workaround would be to change the formula to return only a single element, and have the particular element as an argument in the UDF.

For example:

---

```
Option Explicit
Function longString(Optional R As Long = 1, Optional C As Long = 1)
        Dim res(1 To 1, 1 To 2)
        res(1, 1) = "hellohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\nhellohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\nhellohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\nhellohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhellohh\n"
        res(1, 2) = "world"
        longString = res(R, C)
End Function
```

---

You could then call the function in any of the following ways:

```
=longString()      <-- returns the first element
=longString(1,1)   <-- returns the first element
=longString(1,2)   <-- returns the second element
=longString(ROWS($1:1), COLUMNS($A:A))  <--could be dragged down and right to return an array of the elements
```

Comment: Thanks. The workaround works. Glad to know that it is one of the obscure limitations that only affect arrays.

Comment: Just got an answer from MSDN forum, String array needs to decleared  explicitly. ie. `Dim res(1 To 1, 1 To 2) as String`. Then it'll accept long strings.

Comment: @TerenceHang That's true.  For some reason, when I noticed you had explicitly declared the return type of the function to be Variant, and implicitly declared res as Variant, I gave you a workaround that would preserve those data types. One possibly undesirable side affect of declaring res as string would be that numeric data will be returned as a string; hence ignored by certain functions.