# Error #VALUE with long string in UDF in VBA for output in Excel

Tags: string, vba, excel, excel-udf

I use the below UDF to concatenate references to include the result in 
an SQL query like `ref in ('ref1', 'ref2', ...)`.

The UDF **works just fine normally**, but when I need to put a **huge list of references,

 I get `#VALUE` in Excel**.

I already take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27704505/4628637)**, but I can't manage to make my UDF work...

I've tried to changed the type of the function from `String` to `Variant` (explicitly),
 but it didn't change a thing...

I also tried `ConcatSQL2 = A(0)` and `ConcatSQL2 = A` for the output, 
`Dim A(0 To 0) As String` for the declaration, ... and again it is not working...
 I'm running out of ideas...

For info, the **result string is expected to be about 220k long**... 
To help you generate a lot of text, you can use the [Lorem Ipsum generator here!](http://www.lipsum.com/)

```
Public Function ConcatSQL2(Plage As Range, Optional Doublon As Boolean = True)
Dim A() As String, _
    Cel As Range
ReDim A(0)

A(0) = "('"
For Each Cel In Plage.Cells
    If (Cel.Value <> "" And (InStr(1, A(0), Cel.Value) = 0 Or Doublon)) Then
        A(0) = A(0) & Cel.Value & "', '"
    End If
Next
A(0) = Left(A(0), Len(A(0)) - 3) & ")"

ConcatSQL2 = A(0)
End Function
```

Comment: I directly type it in excel `=ConcatSQL2(A2:A15419;FALSE)`. but as I said it **works fine in normal use**, but when the **output is too long**, I get the **error**... so try to [generate a lot of text](http://www.lipsum.com/) and try it again!

Comment: 32767 is the maximum number of characters in a cell.

Comment: @Rory : Mkay... So my best solution would be to write this in a text file or a word document?

Comment: Not really, the limitation is for a worksheet cell. The VBA variable holds the result with no error, since you are using VBA, just don't post the result in a cell, continue working in VBA.

Comment: Depends what you're doing with the string.

Comment: @Rory : Pasting it into DB software to complete my SQL query, so the text file seems a good solution.

Comment: I think the performance will suck! In clauses are not efficient generally and that's a LOT of values!!

Comment: @Rory : I'm not an SQL pro, but if you know a more efficient way to do this, I'm open to learn!^^ Anyway, even with the `in`, my query only took a few secs. And as I don't have to automate this, I don't really have a performance issue, but always open to suggestion!

Comment: If it works OK I wouldn't worry about it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding @Rory's comments :

> 32767 is the maximum number of characters in a cell

I decided to **write the output in a text file** to be reused afterwards!

Here is the final solution

```
Public Function ConcatSQL2(Plage As Range, Optional Doublon As Boolean = True)
Dim A(0 To 0) As String, _
    myFile As String, _
    Cel As Range
'ReDim A(0)

A(0) = "('"
For Each Cel In Plage.Cells
    If (Cel.Value <> "" And (InStr(1, A(0), Cel.Value) = 0 Or Doublon)) Then
        A(0) = A(0) & Cel.Value & "', '"
    End If
Next
A(0) = Left(A(0), Len(A(0)) - 3) & ")"

myFile = "Path\FileName.txt"
Open myFile For Output As #1
Write #1, A(0)
Close #1

ConcatSQL2 = A
End Function
```